# Delete specific prefixed RDS manual snapshots which are 7 days old

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

I would need some help in deleting the RDS manual snapshots. We create RDS Snapshots daily, but I want to delete snapshots which are 7 days. At the moment it only deletes one snapshot. I want it to delete all those snapshot which starts with the name `rds-test-instance` which are 7 days old.

```py
import boto3


def snap_check(text):
    result = text.startswith('from-rds-test-instance')
    return result


client = boto3.client('rds')
DB = 'rds-test-instance'

#-----Define Lambda function-----#
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    snapshots = client.describe_db_snapshots(
        DBInstanceIdentifier=DB,
        SnapshotType='manual'
        )

    for i in snapshots['DBSnapshots']:
        if snap_check(str(i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'])):
            print(i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'])
```

I have now edited the code and it prints out  the list perfectly. I just now need to put the delete bit in the above code. So that it can delete snapshots which are older then 7 days. Can anyone help please

Comment: can someone please help

Comment: Are you wanting to base the deletion on the Creation Date of the RDS Snapshot, or the Name of the snapshot?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i want the snapshot with the Name. So any snapshot which starts with "rds-test-instance" which was created 7 days ago should be deleted, We only want to create 7days of snapshots

Comment: this is what i am using now instead of last print command del_response = client.delete_db_snapshot(i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'])  but i get an error saying "errorMessage": "delete_db_snapshot() only accepts keyword arguments.",

Answer (score 2):

This is how i achieved the whole scenario. If anyone else is looking

```
    import boto3
    import datetime
    from datetime import datetime, timezone
    from datetime import timedelta

    today = (datetime.today()).date()
    now = today - timedelta(days=7)

    def snap_check(text):
        result = text.startswith('from-rds-test-instance-')
        return result


        client = boto3.client('rds')
        DB = 'rds-test-instance'

#-----Define Lambda function-----#
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    snapshots = client.describe_db_snapshots(
        DBInstanceIdentifier=DB,
        SnapshotType='manual'
        )
    print('Following DB Snapshots will be deleted')
    for i in snapshots['DBSnapshots']:
        if snap_check(str(i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'])) and i ["SnapshotCreateTime"].date() < now:
            print(i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'])
            #del_response = client.delete_db_snapshot(
            #    DBSnapshotIdentifier=i['DBSnapshotIdentifier']
            #    )
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should:

- Call [`describe_db_snapshots()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_snapshots)
- Loop through the list of returned Snapshot and:

  - Check the value for `SnapshotCreateTime`
  - If it is older than 7 days, call `delete_db_snapshot()`

Comment: i read this comment in another thread, but unable to put the logic together. if someone please can help with this. My boto3 is not very good, thats why i am unable to put it together

Comment: I suggest you start by calling `describe_db_snapshots()` and then `print()` the results. You can then see the information that is returned. You can do a loop with: `for snapshot in response['DBSnapshots']: print(snapshot.SnapshotCreateTime)` Let us know if you have a specific problem.

Comment: i have now edited the question above. Can you please check.